# Analog of Reed's conjecture for hypergraph

Tags: graph-colorings, hypergraph

Reed's $\omega$,$\Delta$, $\chi$ conjecture proposes that every graph has $\chi \leq \lceil \tfrac 12(\Delta+1+\omega)\rceil$.  Here $\chi$ is the chromatic number, $\Delta$ is the maximum degree, and $\omega$ is the clique number.

Is there any similar theorem or conjecture that has to do with hypergraph colorings? That is where the vertices can be colored in $\chi$ colors such that no edge is monochromatic.

More helpful for me is the case of coloring where every k-edge has k different colors (Rainbow coloring).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47663/hypergraph-chromatic-number-vs-degree-clique-size?rq=1 answers this for the rainbow case.